# trying to compute the area of a rectangle given the width and the diagonal

Tags: python

I know I'm not defining diagonal somewhere, but this is what I have so far:

```
import math

def compute_height_rectangle(width,diagonal):
    height=area/diagonal
    return height

height = int(input("Please enter the length of the diagonal: "))
"height = int(height) "
width  = int(input("please enter the width: "))
"diagonal = width"

def compute_area_rectangle(width,diagonal):
    area=height*width
    return area

print(compute_area_rectangle(width,diagonal))
```

Comment: You might want to clean up your variables as you swap between `height` and `diagonal` throughout the code. This makes it confusing as to what you actually meant. Start from the beginning and write out on paper each step you want to take to compute the area. Then convert that flow into code. Try to organize your def's in one place rather than all over as it will help with readability

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pythagoras' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), we notice that:

`diagonal^2 = height^2 + width^2 (not python code)`

knowing that the diagonal is always bigger than the height, we have:

`height = sqrt(diagonal^2 - width^2)`

So the code you want is:

```
def compute_height_rectangle(width, diagonal):
    return (diagonal ** 2 - width ** 2) ** 0.5

def compute_area_rectangle(width, diaognal):
    return width * compute_height_rectangle(width, diagonal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Diagonal is never defined because you have the

```
"diagonal = width"
```

in double quotes, which makes it just a string. I copied your code and removed the double quotes and it didn't produce an error. I would also remove the:

```
"height = int(height)"
```

line because there's no need to assign height as an integer input.

For future questions, it would help if you told us what you were trying to make your code do, so we can spot any other errors too, and it might just save you some effort :).